# Problema: Consola de windows no reconoce símbolos Unicode. C# Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, consola, unicode

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación de consola en Visual Studio. Como puedo hacer para que la **consola reconozca símbolos Unicode**?

Al imprimir de la siguiente manera un archivo de texto (en formato Unicode) me imprime lo siguiente:

```
texto = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Principal\Archivo.txt", Encoding.Unicode);
```

**Archivo.txt**: ๑•ิ.•ั๑ ๑۩۞۩๑ ♬✿.｡.:* ★

**Consola**: ??.?? ????? ??.?.:* ?

PD: ya probé con todas las codificaciones de Encoding

Comment: ¿Has probado estableciendo `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`?

Comment: Gracias, eso + lo de Pikoh resolvieron el problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay dos problemas. Por un lado, trata de seleccionar `Unicode` como codificación de la consola:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

Por otro, **que es lo que posiblemente te está pasando**, normalmente la consola utiliza el tipo de letra `Consolas`, que no tiene algunos caracteres. Prueba a pulsar en el menú de la consola (arriba a la izquierda), `Propiedades`, y en la pestaña `Fuente` selecciona una diferente, por ejemplo `Sim sun-ExtB`

Comment: Todo bien ahora. No todos los simboles están en todas las fuentes. Pero es cosa de quedarse con la fuente en la cual estén los símbolos que uno ocupara. Gracias.

Comment: @MaitreyaMorgado si, tambien tienes la opción de añadir fuentes a la consola, aunque so nunca lo he probado. Mira [esto](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-add-fonts-to-the-command-prompt/) si te interesa